# Simulator error for iPhone 8 and X : Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, simulator

I am building a Cordova App for iOS using XCore. It perfectly works on simulator of all devices from iPhone 5S to iPhone 7, and for iPhone 8 Plus.

But I need my app to work for iPhone 8 and iPhone X devices.

Here is my error when I run my app on iPhone 8 or iPhone X. The simulator is turning on, but the app is not installed and I got this error in Xcode  :

```
Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x3
```

I already tried to clean my project, reboot my Mac and Xcode, but I still have the same error. As I said, I have no problem with iPhone 5S, 6, 6S, 6 Plus, 6S Plus, SE, 7, 7 Plus and 8 Plus

I use :

- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6,
- Xcode 9.4
- iOS 11.4

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> 1. Please go to Xcode->Window->Device and Simulators
> 2. Select Simulator option from segment
> 3. Remove simulator and add again